# What materials do we need to run gas line to laundry room?

Tags: dryer

Purchased three bedroom slab ranch home. House has natural gas furnace, stove and hot water tank. There is a dedicated laundry room that has only electrical outlets for washing machine and dryer. Want to run gas line from furnace/hot water tank gas line to laundry room. What materials will we need to accomplish this task? Also, can we use flexible tubing for the gas line? Thank you.

Comment: Where do you live different areas have different regulations.

Comment: Where in the world are you? In Ohio, USA it is pretty common to run CSST now but in the past I mostly see “black pipe

Answer (score 2):

My last house had gas plumbing where the homeowner ran a new line from the water heater line to the laundry room. It was red-tagged as unsafe.

I strongly recommend that you hire out this job; it's one of those "if you have to ask, you shouldn't be doing it" situations. Gas plumbing isn't one of those things that you can mess up and then fix later without any danger or problems.

Answer (score 0):

Tradition is to use "black iron" ( steel that is not galvanized - there is folklore that galvanized is bad in gas so many municipalities prohibit it ) . Personally I would not use flex for a long run even if it is permitted. The final connection should be flexible ( corrugated) stainless. Brass is usually prohibited and should not be used.

Comment: A shutoff prior to the flex is usually required also.

Comment: Yes, I don't think you cam have too many shut-offs